# How long do wild Pokemon need to stay on Isle Abeens before they can join your team?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

On Isle Abeens in Poke Pelago I've had several wild Pokemon visit. When I click on them Mohn tells me that they are enjoying themselves and I should check how they're doing tomorrow. I've tried checking on them 24 hours later and they are gone. How long do Pokemon need to stay on the island before they will want to join your team?

*Extra info: I normally keep the Isle stocked with beans, if this makes any difference.*

Comment: I've had only one join try checking in 10 to 12 hours being that's how long I believe it was another thought is 20 hours since that seems to be a running theme between Pokemon go and the qr scans. I'm still looking into it

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, they require an amount of time close to 24 hours. However, they have to be checked up on every few hours in order to have them stay. 10 hours is fine to go unchecked. So you don't need to stop sleeping. However, you must pay attention to them.

Answer (score -2):

At one point it took me about 1-2 and a half hours for a Pokemon to stay. Doesn't always happen, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Hello, @TrainerCat and welcome to Arqade! Could you explain your answer in alot more detail?